# Google Indexing and Crawling Issue with AngularJs 1.5x , ASP.MVC v4.5 Website along with Prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, prerender, google-index, google-search-console

I am done developing a website with front-end technology as **AngularJs 1.5x** and Server Side technology as **ASP.NET MVC v4.5**. Along with this, I am using **prerender.io** for crawling and Indexing.

Now, after implementing prerender.io, prerender.io is only seemed to be working for Facebook and Twitter Crawling.

**Issue:** My website is not getting indexed by Google. But Prerender.io and the articles related to it says that prerender.io also helps in Google Indexing in Crawling.

But When I am monitoring **Google Search Console** for my website I can only see that only my main URL got indexed. But When I see Fetch and Render results it shows only header and footer of my website but not the full landing page.I even submitted the **sitemap.xml** file but it is also not helping for Indexing.

Read almost all possible articles related to this topic but still seems unable to get thru for Google Indexing and Crawling.

Searched on **StackOverflow** with below URL but the issue still not resolved.

[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Google+Indexing+prerender.io](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Google%20Indexing%20prerender.io)

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you send me an email with your website? I'd be happy to look into this and make sure everything is set up correctly so that Google can see your prerendered pages! todd@prerender.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Configuration works perfectly. The original issue was in Google Indexing. Actually, Google Bot uses **Chrome Version 54** which fails to parse the arrow functions. So by replacing arrow function with the normal function, it started indexing my site.